# Java string.equals(string) not behaving as expected

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, equals

I am getting the occasional odd result from String.equals(String).

here is the code:

```
boolean equals(OutputHolder other){
    boolean result=true;
    if( ! this.speciesEng.equals(other.speciesEng))
        result=false;
    else if( ! this.date.equals(other.date))
        result=false;
    else if( ! this.gridRef.equals(other.gridRef))
        result=false;
    else if( ! this.recorder.equals(other.recorder))
        result=false;
    return result; 
}
```

All pretty straight forward but on some objects .equals() returns false on what appear to be 2 identical strings.
[image]

This is a screenshot of the Expressions watchlist when the error occurs. As you can see this.speciesEng.equals(other.speciesEng) is returning false despite the fact that both strings appear the same.

The strings are initially from the same string resource but both have passed over an XMPP connection and back.

EDIT: To pass them over the XMPP connection, they have been concatenated with other strings to represent the whole OutputHolder. They are then separated on return using .substring(start,end). It occurred to me that it might make a difference if I made a new string from the substring but that didn't have any effect. Neither did trimming them.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed with debugging the problem. Any help or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Try to [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the String before you check for equality.

Comment: You might need to use trim() on Strings before comparing.

Comment: how about the other fields: date, gridRef & recorder?

Comment: Have you tried digging into the `value` fields? And BTW: you should do a `return false` instead of `result=false` to avoid unnecessary comparisons. And if you want your equals() method to be usable with collections, it should be `boolean equals(Object)`

Comment: I imagine that the problem effects the other fields as well. They are treated exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After god knows how many hours copying and pasting from the debugger to a hex editor I have found the problem and a solution that works.

As suggested the problem was whitespaces but not in the way I or (I think) others suspected.
For some reason that I have failed to get to the bottom of, I am getting non-breaking whitespaces (0x00A0) in my strings instead of normal whitespaces (Ox0020). This appears to be happening more or less at random and I haven't found the section of code responsible yet.

The work around at the moment is to start my equals() method with:

```
    speciesEng=speciesEng.replace((char)0x00a0,(char)0x0020);
    other.speciesEng=other.speciesEng.replace((char)0x00a0,(char)0x0020);
    speciesEng=speciesEng.trim();
    other.speciesEng=other.speciesEng.trim();
```

Far from elegant but it works for the moment. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days in case anyone has more to add.

Thanks to all for the answers.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. An odd problem that I doubt is going to crop up very often. I haven't tracked down the offending code yet but once I do I'll post here. Most likely suspect is the file handling where I use a BufferedWriter.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there are no trailing spaces. So better use `trim` method on the strings before comparing them using `equals` method.

Comment: Oops, when I posted the answer, your answer was not there.

Comment: I have just tried this and it makes no difference. If you look at the screenshot you can see that the 2 strings have the same length anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some whitespaces in there. Use [`String#trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method prior to calling equals.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first `trim` both the strings and get rid of additional spaces.
That way you will be able to equate both the `Strings` properly.

Example Code:

```
String yourString = "Your String   ";
//Trim the String and get rid of extra spaces before doing any comparisons.
yourString.trim();
//After trimming it, do the comparisons.
if(yourString.equalsIgnoreCase("other trimmed string"))
{
 .....
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean equals(OutputHolder other){
boolean t1 = speciesEng.equals(other.speciesEng);
boolean t2 = date.equals(other.date);
boolean t3 = gridRef.equals(other.gridRef);
boolean t4 = recorder.equals(other.recorder);
return t1 && t2 && t3 && t4;
```

}

Comment: That was how my code initially looked but I've expanded it to multiple lines so I could debug it easier. The same for the unnecessary this.

Comment: No it failed like that before so I expanded it so I could find where it was failing.